# Arithmetic on Equalities in Distribution: Coincidence?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, independence

I gather that if we have random variables such that $X_1,X_2$ are independent and $Y_1,Y_2$ are independent, then
$$X_1=_dY_1,X_2=_dY_2\implies  X_1+X_2=_dY_1+Y_2,\quad (1)$$

where $=_d$ denotes equal in distribution; the identity can be shown by characteristic functions. Without the independence assumption, we have an easy counterexample: $X_1,Y_1$ standard normal, and $Y_2=Y_1$ and $X_2=-X_1.$

---

Now I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378586/distribution-of-2xy-and-x2-y2-when-x-y-sim-n0-1) question, which asks to show that for $X,Y$ independent standard normals, $2XY=_dX^2-Y^2.$ I understand how to show this correctly  (e.g. using the joint distribution of $(X+Y,X-Y)$ to show $X+Y,X-Y$ are iid $\sqrt 2 N(0,1)$). However, consider the following **incorrect** argument I thought of:

> We know $2Y^2=_d(X-Y)^2.$ Then adding $2XY-2Y^2$ to both sides gives $2XY=_d X^2-Y^2.$

Note that this argument is not justified by $(1)$ since $2Y^2$ and $2XY-2Y^2$ are not independent since they are not even uncorrelated:

$$E[2Y^2(2XY-2Y^2)]=E[4XY^3-4Y^4]=4\underbrace{E[X]E[Y^3]}_{=0}-4E[Y^4]=-12\\
\neq E[2Y^2]E[2XY-2Y^2]=4E[Y^2]\underbrace{E[X]E[Y]}_{=0}-4(E[Y^2])^2=-4.$$

So why does the incorrect argument give the correct result? Is it a coincidence, or is there something special here about normal distributions going on?